# Dumping Memory of a SystemVerilog Class

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Is there a way to dump a memory content of a memory that is used in a class instead of using `$writememh()` system task? I want to check for memory content in the predictor class of a UVM environment used in a UVM scoreboard. I am using 2016 Synopsys VCS simulation vendor

E.g. say I have a predictor:

```
class my_predictor extends uvm_subscriber#(my_item);
  `uvm_component utils(my_predictor)

  logic [15:0] mem [512];  // Want to observe the change of this mem content

   ...
   /* local logics, constructor, phase(s) and write function definitions */
   ...

endclass : my_predictor
```

I have tried the following:

```
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    forever begin
    $vcdplusmemon(mem);
endtask : run_phase
```

But I was unable to observe it even when I load `vcdplus.vpd`. I then setup for `simv` in DVE and then ran. When I tried to view the waveform of `my_predictor.mem`, DVE crashed.

My motivation for doing this is to compare my predicted change of memory content with the actual memory content of the DUT I am testing via a constrained randomized test.

Is it a vendor tool feature limitation?

Comment: Basically, you want to observe an array class data member in the waveform display of DVE. Is that right?

Comment: I do not thing that vcddump works with dynamic objects, i.e. classes.  Move your `mem` in a **module**.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Yes. That's basically it. I want to observe the waveform display to identify the correct time of value changes in the array of the class data member.